# cloud9,rails s, Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

when i do the opration with the doc of cloud9 https://docs.c9.io/running_a_rails_app.html

finally, i write the code ***rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0***

then the mistake show:

```
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)                                                                                                                                                               
   。。。。。。                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

     Error: you may be using the wrong PORT & HOST for your server app
```

Cloud9  For rails, use: 'rails s -p $PORT -b $IP'
         For Sinatra, use: ruby app.rb -p $PORT -o $IP'

whatever i try the ip and port, the mistake is the mistake .

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with the cloud9 IDE, but assuming you have some access to your environment ... I would try to solve this in the following ways

1. Make sure your environment variables are correct

   `echo '$PORT' # should be '3000' per your question`

   `echo '$IP' # should be '0.0.0.0' per your question`
2. Run your web server on port 80 with rvmsudo (port 80 because of what might be happening in your iptables -- see #2)

   `rvmsudo rails s -b 0.0.0.0`
3. Modify your iptables to allow traffic on port 3000

   `sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

   Add the line: `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000:7010 -j ACCEPT`
4. Change the user, group and permissions on your webrick files (obviously change your 'user' and 'group'):

   `sudo chown user:group /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/webrick/*`

   `sudo chmod 755 /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/webrick/*`

When done you might want to change the permissions on your webrick files to something more strict later.